# Preventing deletion of model instance in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and would like to prevent deletion of a specific model instance - this instance has a specific 'key' that I'm happy to hard-code.

**Model Class**

```py
class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
```

In Django, I'd do something like

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField()

    def delete(self, **kwargs):
        if self.key == 'my-undeletable-key':
            raise MyCustomException()
        super(MyModel, self).delete(**kwargs)
```

Is there a SQLAlchemy equivalent?

Comment: yes it is the same thing! you can define method on model class in sqlalchemy

Comment: It is also a good fail-safe measure to set user permissions such that users cannot delete from specific tables.